# How high can sand pile up?

Tags: forces

I read a question about sand. In one answer, an hourglass was mentioned.
Suppose you have enough fine, dry sand. If you create a pile of sand by letting a beam of sand fall down on the land (like in an hourglass), how high can the pile get?

Will the pile collapse under its own weight at a certain height, or can you make it as high as you want?  Say the pile is placed on an infinite plane with a uniform gravity. Will it get flatter and flatter if you pour in more sand (like water flattens if you pour it onto the plane)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose

Comment: If you have "enough sand" you could go as high as you want. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If it gets hundreds or thousands of kilometers high the grains at the bottom will be crushed. But I assume you mean idealized indestructible sand.  :>)